# What happens if multiple windows have the "Always stay on the top" option enabled?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

Can someone tell me what the option "Always stay on the top" in Windows for various applications stand for?

If there are multiple applications with the same option selected, what will the option do in that case?

Kindly guide me!

Comment: Why the lol? I fail to get what is so funny...

Comment: Well it was actually about the Windows preference, but while writing it it also sounded funny to me, appreciate a little humor guys!

Comment: And how is not a real question, have u guys ever wondered if multiple applications have the same option selected what happens then, so i think it is quite useless if not kindly guide me.

Comment: If that is really what you want to know, then that is what you should have asked in the question.

Comment: Well I think asking a generic thing would have brought the details, well my bad ok, but at least a good comment to clarify would have better before closing the question. I still dint get my answer.

Comment: Asking a generic question expecting a specific answer is actually the exact opposite intention of this site.

Comment: Well moreover I think it is also not that much generic where else would U find always stay on top option, being asked on this site, except a little humor that u dont appreciate no problem.

Comment: When you write your question, it actually says: "What is your […] question? **Be specific**". You can still edit your question and maybe try to clarify.

Comment: That was one good suggestion and I edited the question and accept the mistake on my part!

Comment: Okay, you got my green light, voted to reopen.

Comment: Raymond Chen talks about it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: Well not able to make out any thing much from blog

Comment: What happens when an unstoppable object runs into an unmovable object. The end of the world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I barely understand your question, but I think you want to know what "Always stay on top" Window preference does. This forces that window to always be on top of others, thus no other window will be over it.

Comment: Well my question was the same one, but while writing it also sounded funny, I never think choosing that option ever helps. What if multiple windows are selected with the same option. That was my question

Comment: Those window behave like that option is not set between them.

Comment: When multiple windows are pinned to stay on top, All of those programs set that way will always be on top of programs that are not set that way.  The Always on top "layer" of applications can still be jumped foreward and backwards of eachother, by gaining focus, or alt tabbing, or taskbar selection.
The pinned to top layer behaves just like a normal layer in most other respects.
Any "Always on top" item can still be on top of an "always on top" item just like the rest of the system functions.

I think i had it described best when it is simply 2 Layers , the ones that stay on top, & the rest.

Comment: That's what I said